# Replot a deleted object MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

Is it possible to replot a line after it has been deleted, using properties previously retrieved by 'get()'.

For example:

```
% Create the plot and 'get' its properties.
axes
P = plot(1:360, sind(1:360));
PG = get(P);

% Delete the plot.
delete(P)

% Replot the line...
plot(PG)  % ?????
```

I'd like it to be generalizable, i.e. the solution would work for surface plots, line plots, text annotations, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Approach 1: Don't delete it, make it invisible

Instead of deleting and recreating the object, you could make it invisible:

```
set(P, 'visible', 'off')
```

and then visible again

```
set(P, 'visible', 'on')
```

### Approach 2: Create object and set property values with loop

If you really want to recreate a deleted object, you can proceed as follows: create an object of the same type and use a `for` loop to set its properties to the stored values. A [`try`-`catch`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/try.html) block is needed because some properties are read-only and issue an error.

```
%// Replot the object...
Q = plot(NaN); %// create object. Plot any value
fields = fieldnames(PG);
for n = 1:numel(fields)
    try
        set(Q, fields{n}, getfield(PG, fields{n})); %// set field
    catch
    end
end
```

You can use this approach with other types of graphics objects, such as `surf`, but then you have to change the line that creates the object (first line in the code above). For example, with `surf` it would be something like

```
Q = surf(NaN(2)); %// create object. surf needs matrix input
```

I have tested this in R2010b with `plot` and with `surf`.

### Approach 3: Make a copy of the object and restore it, using `copyobj`

Use [`copyobj`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) to make a copy of the object in another (possibly invisible) figure, and then recover it from that. This automatically works for any object type.

```
%// Create the plot
P = plot(1:360, sind(1:360));
a = gca; %// get handle to axes

%// Make a copy in another figure
f_save = figure('visible','off');
a_save = gca;
P_saved = copyobj(P, a_save);

%// Delete the object
delete(P)

%// Recover it from the copy
P_recovered = copyobj(P_saved, a);
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I suspected it might require something like that. I can't edit the visible property for reasons I didn't mention in the question; basically there's a bug that I can't isolate that is deleting the line itself when I am plotting other objects, and I'm trying to come up with a work around to replot those child objects that go missing. I'll give your loop a go...

Comment: The advantage of this answer using `try-catch` is that read-only-fields are handled directly and the code will work with other types of objects without first removing the read-only fields. In my answer this has to be done manually.

Comment: I've included a cleaner approach using `copyobj`

Comment: Great, thanks. That does the job. I added a switch-case block to get the object type so that I can generalize it for line, surf, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store the object as a struct `PG` with the `get`-command (as you already did) and then set all the parameters at once with the `set`-command. There are some read-only fields, that need to be removed before setting them and the objects must be of the same type. In the following example, we create a plot with `plot(0)` that is being overwritten with the data from the previous plot.

```
% Create the plot
figure
P = plot(1:360, sind(1:360));

% Store plot object
PG = get(P);

% Delete the plot
delete(P);

% Remove read-only fields of plot object
PG = rmfield(PG,{'Annotation','BeingDeleted','Parent','Type'});

% Create a new plot
figure
P = plot(0);

% Set the parameters
set(P,PG);
```

*If you don't want to manually remove the fields, use a `try-catch`-block and iterate over all the fields as described in Luis Mendo's answer.*

Comment: The problem with this approach (which was my now deleted attempt as well) is that it doesn't seem to adapt well to e.g. surf.

Comment: Thanks, I like the appeal of removing the loop and doing it in one line, but as you say Luis Mendo's try-catch block means you don't have to preassign the read-only fields.